# Fuser shows non-existing processes, so NVIDIA GPU reset fails

Tags: nvidia, process-management, lsof, fuser

I am trying to reset an NVIDIA A100 card that still has memory occupied, but no process is using it. First, I killed all processes using any NVIDIA card with

```
sudo fuser -k /dev/nvidia*
```

then run the reset command

```
sudo nvidia-smi -r
```

However, it tells me, there are still processes using the GPUs. When I run `sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*`, it lists a few `gpustat` and `nvidia-smi` processes with their PIDs. However, `ps aux | grep $PID` does not return anything (except the `grep` process itself) and `sudo kill $PID` results in `kill: ($PID): No such process`. `lsof` shows me the same non-existing processes.

Why are there still processes left in the records that apparently don't exist anymore and how to get rid of them?